# Lightning Object Page Custom Button With No Redirect

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, callout, custom-button

I have a custom button that makes a callout. I know how to do this by creating a VFP and creating the custom button on the object with the custom URL, but I am curious if there is a better/ supported way with lightning? Two of the three options on a custom button are not really supported anymore (JS and VFP) so that just leaves the URL and I am not sure if there is a way to hook a LWC into the url...any thoughts on this? Do we still think VFP is the best route with custom buttons?

Comment: You could use a LWC [Headless Quick Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless)

Comment: interesting alternative. do you think this is best practice or do you think VFP is still the preferred method at this time?

Comment: I would prefer a LWC quick action over VFP

Comment: Because lightning quick actions does not support all objects (like Quote and Task), what would be your next best option? Would you wrap the LWC in an aura component?

Comment: Yes, for unsupported object I would wrap the LWC in an Aura component.